# This combat loop is too complicated. How do I simplify/fix it?

Tags: python

I've only been writing code for about 2 weeks.

I have no idea how to fix this, and it's getting extremely repetitive. If there is a way to simplify the idea, how would I go about doing that?

As you can see, it'll start the combat, assign goblin to 30 then keep on doing the same combat regime over and over and over.

```
def combatGoblinOne():

  goblin = 30
  goblindam = 5

  print("\nYou enter combat!")
  print("What would you like to do?")
  print('[1]', myPlayer.aone, ', [2]', myPlayer.atwo)

  print("\n-------------------------")
  print("Goblin ----------- Player")
  print("HP =", goblin, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
  print("-------------------------")
  spellChoice = int(input('-> '))
  if spellChoice == 1:

    goblin = goblin - 10
    print("\nGoblin loses 10 health!", goblin, "health left!")
    print("\n-------------------------")
    print("Goblin ----------- Player")
    print("HP =", goblin, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
    print("-------------------------")

    print("\nGoblin slashes you, dealing", goblindam, "damage.")
    myPlayer.hp = myPlayer.hp - goblindam
    print("\n-------------------------")
    print("Goblin ----------- Player")
    print("HP =", goblin, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
    print("-------------------------")

    print("\nWhat would you like to do?")
    print('[1]', myPlayer.aone, ', [2]', myPlayer.atwo)
    spellChoice1 = int(input('-> '))
    if spellChoice1 == 1:
      goblin = goblin - 10
      print("\nGoblin loses 10 health!", goblin, "health left!")
      print("\n-------------------------")
      print("Goblin ----------- Player")
      print("HP =", goblin, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
      print("-------------------------")
    if spellChoice1 == 2:
      myPlayer.hp = 80
      print("\nYou return to 80 HP")
      print("\n-------------------------")
      print("Goblin ----------- Player")
      print("HP =", goblin, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)

      print("\nGoblin slashes you, dealing", goblindam, "damage.")
      myPlayer.hp = myPlayer.hp - goblindam
      print("\n-------------------------")
      print("Goblin ----------- Player")
      print("HP =", goblin, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
      print("-------------------------")
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion, create classes for the player which you may already have done and another for the enemy. Then write some functions to handle the combat that way you dont have to repeat yourself.

```
class Player():

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.aone='cast'
        self.atwo='heal'
        self.hp=80

class Enemy():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Goblin'
        self.hp = 30
        self.dmg = 5

def combat(spell, myPlayer, enemy):
    if spell == 1:
        enemy.hp = enemy.hp - 10
        print("\n{} loses 10 health! {} health left!".format(enemy.name, enemy.hp))
        print("\n-------------------------")
        print("Goblin ----------- Player")
        print("HP =", enemy.hp, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
        print("-------------------------")
        if enemy.hp > 0:
            enemyAttack(myPlayer, enemy)

    if spell == 2:
        myPlayer.hp = 80
        print("\nYou return to 80 HP")
        print("\n-------------------------")
        print("Goblin ----------- Player")
        print("HP =", enemy.hp, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
        if enemy.hp > 0:
            enemyAttack(myPlayer, enemy)



def enemyAttack(myPlayer, enemy):
    print("\n{} slashes you, dealing {} damage.".format(enemy.name, enemy.dmg))
    myPlayer.hp = myPlayer.hp - enemy.dmg
    print("\n-------------------------")
    print("Goblin ----------- Player")
    print("HP =", enemy.hp, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
    print("-------------------------")

def combatGoblinOne(myPlayer, goblin):

    print("\nYou enter combat!")
    while(goblin.hp > 0 and myPlayer.hp > 0):
        print("What would you like to do?")
        print('[1]', myPlayer.aone, ', [2]', myPlayer.atwo)
        print("\n-------------------------")
        print("Goblin ----------- Player")
        print("HP =", goblin.hp, "           HP =", myPlayer.hp)
        print("-------------------------")
        spellChoice = int(input('-> '))
        combat(spellChoice, myPlayer, goblin)


myPlayer = Player()
goblin = Enemy()
combatGoblinOne(myPlayer, goblin)
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. I voted for this answer because of two insightful observations, one that it needs classes and functions and two that the code is repeating itself. We don't generally provide alternate solutions.

Comment: Why are you calling `super().__init__()` in `Player` and `Enemy` when they're not inheriting from a superclass? Also, PEP 8 naming conventions say that `enemyAttack` should be `enemy_attack`, and `myPlayer` should be `my_player`.

Answer (score -3):

Start by writing and calling *[functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)*: as soon as you are writing the same code two times, you should write a function.

Then, for this kind of application, you should learn about [`class`es](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), allowing you to define a `goblin` object and a `player` object, to simplify your code drasticaly. I wrote some functions for you:

```
def print_state(goblin,player_hp):
    print("\n-------------------------")
    print("Goblin ----------- Player")
    print("HP =", goblin, "           HP =", player_hp)
    print("-------------------------")


def goblin_loss_10life(goblin,player_hp):
    goblin = goblin - 10
    print("\nGoblin loses 10 health!"+ str(goblin) +"health left!")
    print_state(goblin, player_hp)
    return goblin

def you_loose_life(goblin,player_hp,goblindam):
    player_hp = player_hp - goblindam
    print("\nGoblin slashes you, dealing"+str(goblindam), "damage.")
    print_state(goblin, player_hp)
    return player_hp

def return_to_80(goblin,player_hp):
    print("\nYou return to 80 HP")
    print_state(goblin, myPlayer.hp)
    return 80


def combatGoblinOne():

  goblin = 30
  goblindam = 5

  print("\nYou enter combat!")
  print("What would you like to do?")
  print('[1]', myPlayer.aone, ', [2]', myPlayer.atwo)

  print_state(goblin,myPlayer.hp)

  spellChoice = int(input('-> '))

  if spellChoice == 1:
    goblin      = goblin_loss_10life(goblin,myPlayer.hp)
    myPlayer.hp = you_loose_life(goblin, myPlayer.hp, goblindam)

    print("\nWhat would you like to do?")
    print('[1]', myPlayer.aone, ', [2]', myPlayer.atwo)
    spellChoice1 = int(input('-> '))
    if spellChoice1 == 1:
      goblin = goblin_loss_10life(goblin,myPlayer.hp)

    if spellChoice1 == 2:
      myPlayer.hp = return_to_80(goblin,player_hp)
      myPlayer.hp = you_loose_life(goblin, myPlayer.hp, goblindam)
```

Comment: Why do you switch between `camelCase` and `snake_case` when naming methods and variables? `snake_case` is the standard for naming in Python, according to PEP 8.

Comment: I did not. I used only `snake_case`, but i left the original `cameCase` nomenclature since i thought the OP might need it's names to stay the same. But you a right, this is not uniform.